# SQL Count data from 10pm till 2am (The next day)

Tags: sql

I am puzzle if this is correct if i want to count the number of people sign in to my premises from e.g. 16 Oct 2013 at 10pm to 17 Oct 2013 2am.

It look fine on my end, i just to ask is this the correct way to do it or I will left out some data that over 12am?

```
SELECT COUNT (SignInLog.PlayerID) as '10pm-230am'
FROM SignInLog inner join Members
ON 
Members.ID = SignInLog.PlayerID and
SignIn >= '2013-09-01' and
SignOut <= '2013-10-01' and
DATEPART(hh, SignIn) >= 22 and 
DATEPART(hh, SignOut) <= 3 
and KioskID=1
and Members.MemberCategory Between 1 and 13
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can left join with just `Members.ID = SignInLog.PlayerID` and everything else take to `WHERE` clause, if you gonna use some different join (left or right) this don't gonna be very right...

Comment: Your code does not match the question. You ask for people who signed in but your query lists people who both signed in and out in the period. People who signed in before or signs out after the period are not included.

Comment: @adrianm I think you have a great point, changed my answer to fit your comment

Answer (score 0):

It seems your dates are messed up, you have exchanged month and day.
It is not the correct way, your performance will be terrible because of the calculation on datepart, try this instead:

```
SELECT COUNT (SignInLog.PlayerID) as '10pm-230am'
FROM SignInLog inner join Members
ON 
Members.ID = SignInLog.PlayerID and
SignOut >= '2013-10-16T22:00:00' and
SignIn  <= '2013-10-17T02:00:00' and -- changed it according to question
KioskID=1 and
Members.MemberCategory Between 1 and 13
```

Note: After reading @Adrianms comment, I changed my answer. Now if people have any overlap the query will find it. imagine person signing in at 2013-10-16 15:00 and/or signing out at 2013-10-17 04:00

Comment: You forgot the 'T' and seconds are not optional. i.e. '2013-09-01T22:00:00'

Comment: I am getting those who sign in at this period of 10pm to the next day 2am for everyday. that why it run from 1/9/13 to 1/10/13

Comment: @user2378645 I understand what you are trying to do. It is a terrible way to write your date, yy-dd-mm is not accepted anywhere i know of. Most likely your result will contain an entire month, but only morning and night. Test my script please, it uses a safe conversion

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, from what I gather using a `CAST` should work here:

```
SELECT COUNT (SignInLog.PlayerID) as '10pm-230am'
FROM SignInLog inner join Members
ON 
Members.ID = SignInLog.PlayerID and
SignIn >= CAST('2013-09-01 22:00:00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET) and
SignOut <= CAST('2013-10-01 03:00:00' AS DATETIMEOFFSET) and
and KioskID=1
and Members.MemberCategory Between 1 and 13
```